# Circle to Circle collision - bad accuracy

Tags: java, 2d, collision-detection, mathematics

Circle1 (blue) is moving and its X and Y bounds are the screen (meaning it bounces off the walls).

Circle2 (black) is stationary. Circle1(blue) is supposed to bounce off of Circle2 **without intersecting**, regardless of the collision point. As you can see on the image below, the blue circle bounces off properly only at the blue arrow spots, otherwise(red arrows), blue ball goes **INSIDE** the black circle, gets stuck in there for a second and then gets out.

I have no idea why this is happening. Please take a look at my code and help me out.
Thanks.

[image]

```
public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
                if (counter++ % 5 == 0) {
                    // Moves the ball depending on the values of X and Y
                    circle.setLayoutX(circle.getLayoutX() + X); //velocity
                    circle.setLayoutY(circle.getLayoutY() + Y); //velocity

// Bounce off the walls (working perfectly)
                    final Bounds bounds = canvas.getBoundsInLocal();
                    boolean leftWall = circle.getLayoutX() <= (bounds.getMinX() + circle.getRadius());
                    boolean topWall = circle.getLayoutY() <= (bounds.getMinY() + circle.getRadius());
                    boolean rightWall = circle.getLayoutX() >= (bounds.getMaxX() - circle.getRadius());
                    boolean bottomWall = circle.getLayoutY() >= (bounds.getMaxY() - circle.getRadius());


//THE PROBLEM IS HERE

//Collision between circle1 and circle2 (stationary black circle.                                
                    double dx = circle.getLayoutX() - circle2.getLayoutX();
                    double dy = circle.getLayoutY() - circle2.getLayoutY();
                    double radii = circle.getRadius() + circle2.getRadius();

                    if ( (dx * dx) + (dy * dy) <= radii * radii) {
                        X = X * -1; //X gets inverted to change direction

                    }



 //The code below is working perfectly.
                    // If the bottom or top wall has been touched, the ball reverses direction.
                    if (bottomWall || topWall) {

                        Y = Y * -1;
                        //circle.setLayoutY(circle.getLayoutY() - 50); - Wasn't working. Had to create X and Y to fix the problem.

                    }
                    // If the left or right wall has been touched, the ball reverses direction.
                    if (leftWall || rightWall) {
                        X = X * -1;
                    }                
                }
            }

        }));

        loop.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        loop.play();
    }
```

P.S. Apologies for the amazing paint skills :D

Comment: It seems you only invert the X velocity? `X = X * -1;`

Comment: Yes. if I also invert Y, the ball simply goes backwards, then upwards to the same spot and gets stuck in that small range forever. I tried only reversing Y, and not X, but that didn't help solve the problem.

Comment: You need to calculate a collision normal, and reflect the velocity across that normal.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not well-aware of that. Can you please provide a quick code example of how I can do that?

Comment: surface normal is `normalize(cirlce1.center-circle2.center)` reflection is `2*dot(surfNormal, velocity)*surfNormal-velocity` in vector math (see [the formula for specular reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specular_reflection#Direction_of_reflection))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this tutorial on circle-circle collisions: http://gamedev.tutsplus.com/tutorials/implementation/when-worlds-collide-simulating-circle-circle-collisions/

You seem to have most of the code implemented - go down to Step 4 (I think that's it anyway). It shows you how to calculate the new velocities.

You might have to change how you calculate your updates, as you have to update `circle` and `circle2`'s velocities at the same time (I'm not sure how that works for you).

Note, I could post some of the equations here, but 1. it'd be just a copy-paste (not sure about plagiarism), and 2. they are quite long.

Comment: I appreciate it nevertheless! Would have +1'd if I had the reputation :)

Comment: np :-). If this works for you, you can accept it.